# MongoDB Change Streams watch performance & match params

Tags: mongodb

I have a microservice that watches Notifications collection (~300k docs at the moment) for new insertions & sends them to Firebase.

To do so I use a change stream:

```
const notificationsStream = notifications.watch([
  {
    '$match': { 
      'operationType': 'insert',
      'fullDocument.sent': false,
    }
  }
])

// And then Firebase logic:
notificationsStream.on('change', async next => { ...
```

Will I benefit by limiting $match params to match only recent documents?

Something like this:

```
const now = new Date()
const tenMinutesAgo = new Date(now - 1 * 60 * 1000)
const match = { 
  'operationType': 'insert',
  'fullDocument.sent': false,
  'fullDocument.createdAt': { $gte: tenMinutesAgo },
} 

const notificationsStream = notifications.watch([
  {
    '$match': match 
  }
])

setInterval(() => {
  const newTenMinutesAgo = new Date(new Date() - 1 * 60 * 1000)
  match['fullDocument.createdAt'].$gte = newTenMinutesAgo
}, 60 * 1000) // Adjust every minute
```

I feel like I should, but how do I measure that?

For example, when I open Compass and look into the Performance tab of this DB, I can always see this stream in the Slowest Operations block, GETMORE operation about 0.5-1 seconds. And when I add time limit to my stream I can't see any difference.